# Executing 'npm install' before publishing ASP.NET MVC 5.0 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, msbuild, npm-install

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5.0 application, and I have introduced a `package.json` file to manage JavaScript packages in my project (I reference the node_modules path in my BundleConfig.cs to pull in the packages).

When I pull down a new version of the project and build it, Visual Studio seems to automatically retrieve the NPM packages (I'm assuming Visual Studio 2017 has built in support for this).

However, when I publish my application, the node_modules folder does not get generated. I added the following build target to my web .csproj file in the hope this would resolve the dependencies on publishing:

```
  <Target Name="PrepublishScript" AfterTargets="PrepareForPublish">
    <Exec Command="npm install"/>
  </Target>
```

However, the command doesn't appear to be executed.

The `npm` command is definitely part of my path (i.e. when I open a command window and type npm it executes).

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Is this even a reasonable approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<Target Name="CustomPostPublishActions" AfterTargets="GatherAllFilesToPublish"> 
   <Exec Command="npm install" WorkingDirectory="$(PublishUrl)"></Exec>
</Target>
```

**$(PublishUrl)** appears to be a built-in variable which I used to ensure that the command was executed in the folder where my published files are being output to.

One caveat is that this doesn't really help when it comes to one-click publish with IIS Web Deploy, I'm not sure what I would need to do for that.